# I need to position Circle Avatar and Elevated Button. I tried but it not work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to position CircleAvatar and ElevatedButton. I tried but it does not work plz help solve it. Thank you...

> [image]
>
> i need to add CircleAvatar and ElevatedButton like this.
>
> [image]

Comment: Could you offer a bit more of your code? Are those in a row or a list tile?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the widgets are laid out. I can suggest the simplest way:

```dart
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,        
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              CircleAvatar(),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              ElevatedButton(child: Text('Life'), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              CircleAvatar(),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              ElevatedButton(child: Text('HardWork'), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              CircleAvatar(),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              ElevatedButton(child: Text('Failure'), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      );
```